# Cuando reinicio Ubuntu Server mi configuración DNS se pierde

Tags: ubuntu

Estoy con una máquina virtual con Ubuntu Server y cuando modifico el host o cambio de servidor DNS y reinicio Ubuntu la configuración que introduje se pierde y vuelve a estar como antes (como un estado de fábrica).

Por ejemplo, en el archivo `resolv.conf` aparece `nameserver 127.0.0.53` lo cual hace que por ejemplo no pueda hacer un `ping` a `www.google.com` pero si a su dirección IP. Configuro ese archivo y hago el `ping`, y funciona, pero reinicio Ubuntu Server y se pierde esa configuración que introduje y aparece de nuevo `127.0.0.53`.

Además pasa igualmente con el hostname.

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Que yo recuerde el fichero resolv.conf se regenera en cada reinicio, de hecho la segunda línea dice: "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN". Al menos en Ubuntu, no sé Ubuntu Server.

Comment: La cuestión es porque se reinicia toda la configuración

Comment: has mencionado solo /etc/resolv.conf y /etc/hostname, ¿qué más configuración se resetea?

Comment: He observado mas detalladamente y no se borra toda la configuración, el archivo de interfaces lo configuré y sigue igual. El problema es que no sé como hacer que funcione el DNS. Cuando hago ping a un dominio no funciona y cuando lo hago a su IP si funciona. Igualmente cambio el nombre del host pero se cambia igualmente. La verdad es que no sé que pasa muy bien.

Comment: Creo que deberias replantear tu pregunta. Tu problema es establecer la configuración de DNS, y establecer el hostname del servidor. Lo que pregutnas ahroa (la conf se pierde) diría que es un síntoma de que estás configurandolo una forma inadecuada.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir en la pregunta el contenido del archivo `/etc/network/interfaces`? ¿Qué versión exacta de ubuntu server usas? ¿Tienes activado inicio de sesión gráfica o sólo texto?

Answer (score 1):

La configuración de DNS debe establecerse en el archivo de configuración `/etc/network/interfaces` a través del parámetro `dns-nameservers`.

Ejemplo:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask x.x.x.x
    network x.x.x.x
    broadcast x.x.x.x
    gateway x.x.x.x
    dns-nameservers x.x.x.x y.y.y.y z.z.z.z
    dns-search local.minet
```

El nombre de host debe estar en `/etc/hostname` y coincidir con lo que tiene `/etc/hosts`.

Ejemplo de `/etc/hostname`:

```
miequipo
```

Ejemplo de `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
x.x.x.x     miequipo.local.minet     miequipo

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Por último: ten en cuenta que si es una máquina virtual es probable que tenga instalado algún agente de configuración automática. Si estos cambios no se mantienen tras un reinicio pregunta a tu proveedor de servicios de virtualización.

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda, acabo de solucionar el error introduciendo al arhchivo interface: dns-search example.org

¿Pero qué significa example.org? Además de todo, tengo muchas dudas de como funciona un Ubuntu Server y tengo dudas como esta. Abriré otro tema para explicar mis dudas brevemente.

Gracias a todos por la ayuda!!

Comment: Es un dominio de ejemplo. Sólo sirve para apoyar las resoluciones DNS negativas, agregando dicho dominio de búsqueda en un segundo intento. ¿Probaste a introducir los servidores DNS como te indiqué? Es posible que con sólo indicar un parámetro `dns-*` se cancele la asignación obtenida por DHCP. Si compartieras tu archivo `interfaces` (censurando las direcciones IP) podría explicarte mejor qué ha pasado.

Comment: Ahora el problema es tener un servidor local y que un DNS externo resuelve los dominios del servidor

Comment: ¿Qué es para ti un "servidor local"? Me imagino que te refieres a un servidor web con IP local y que se accede a él desde el exterior mediante una IP pública y redirección de puertos, ¿no es así? ¿Ese servidor DNS externo permite vistas (si es bind9 o el servidor DNS de microsoft entonces seguro que sí)? Si es así puedes configurar que desde tu IP la resolución DNS sea a una IP interna y que desde el resto de IPs la resolución sea a la IP externa. En caso contrario podrías configurar un servidor DNS en tu servidor local que realizara la resolución correcta o mediante vistas o superposición.

Comment: No estoy comprendiendo nada, hice lo que me pusiste como solución y no funciona. Tampoco entiendo para que sirve resolv.conf, es para redes locales o para salir a Internet? Instalo ubuntu server y a veces me funciona el DNS externo y otras veces no.

Comment: Es un servidor DNS solo en local, pero no estoy comprendiendo casi nada debido a que no sé que hace cada fichero ni cada línea de los ficheros

Answer (score 0):

Para el DNS, Debieras editar `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Vas a ver una línea que dice

```
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

Descoméntala y pon el DNS que pones en `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Para el hostname, es posible que el servicio `cloud-init` sea el que te pisa el hostname. Revisa si existe el archivo `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` y donde dice

```
preserve_hostname: false
```

Lo cambias a `true`.

**Edit: otro camino posible**

Debiera haber un directorio llamado

`/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`

dentro de él debiera haber un archivo:

`/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`

Prueba poner en él

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
<línea en blanco>
```

la línea en blanco es importante.

Luego pruebas reiniciando o bien hacienndo `sudo resolvconf -u`

Respecto al hostname que pones en `/etc/hostname` primero asegúrate de incluirlo en `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1  mi-hostname
```

Y prueba hacer `sudo hostname mi-hostname`

**Pregunta adicional**

Revisaste si existe `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` ?

Comment: Pero se supone que resolv.conf se resetea cada vez que reinicias ubuntu

Comment: Se resetea porque explícitamente dice: "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY" por eso debieras configurar el DNS en `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Comment: No funicona. En resolv.conf tengo nameserver 127.0.0.53 y abajo search 1.1.1.1. Modifico dhclient.conf y pongo 127.0.0.53 y sigue sin funcionar. Incluso puse 1.1.1.1

Comment: Pero... tú dijiste que al reiniciar se pierde lo que pusiste en `/etc/resolv.conf` y se pisa con `127.0.0.53`. ¿Cual es la IP del dns que quieres que se persista?

Comment: La dirección 1.1.1.1

Comment: Añadí un par de sugerencias adicionales. Veamos si funcionan

Comment: No funciona, no sé porque pero todavía me sigue sin resolver por ejemplo www.google.com